# Fazer um Foreach em XML com ids e armazenar em uma variável para inserir dados em uma determinada tabela

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach

Boa tarde,

Seguinte, tenho um sistema que já tenho os ids cadastrados em uma tabela, ( de carros , são opicionais de carros) e na outra tabela onde fica cadastrado os carros chama-se essas IDS ja cadastradas, o sistema só le no banco de dados da tabela veiculos os ids cadastrados no campo opcionais...exemplo na tabela fica cadastrado assim

opcionais e embaixo :
1,24,45,57,54

Os ids sao cadastrados e registrado de acordo com o que o usuário precisa, neste caso como estou pegando do xml LOGO abaixo mostrarei..

eu preciso pegar os IDS do XML e colocar eles inseridos na coluna separados por , e para isso se não me engano precisarei usar um foreach.. e armazenar os valores separados somente por "," para inserir na coluna..
Abaixo o XML dos Opcionais

```
<opcionais>
<opcional id="54">Air bag</opcional>
<opcional id="4">Alarme</opcional>
<opcional id="6">Ar condicionado</opcional>
<opcional id="40">Volante com regulagem de altura</opcional>
<opcional id="57">Volante em couro</opcional>
<opcional id="56">Volante espumado</opcional>
</opcionais>
```

So Alguns Opcionais como exemplo.

teria como me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes testar :

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<opcionais>
    <opcional id="54">Air bag</opcional>
    <opcional id="4">Alarme</opcional>
    <opcional id="6">Ar condicionado</opcional>
    <opcional id="40">Volante com regulagem de altura</opcional>
    <opcional id="57">Volante em couro</opcional>
    <opcional id="56">Volante espumado</opcional>
</opcionais>
XML;
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$ids = array();
foreach($sxml->children() as $opcional)
{ 
    echo $opcional['id'];
    $ids[] = $opcional['id'];
}
$idsBd = implode(',', $ids);

include 'connect.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO sua_tabela (sua_coluna) VALUES ('$idsBD')";     
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "realizado!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
}
else
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
?>
```

Verifica suas variáveis de conexão e etc...

Leitura recomendada [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: No, de primeira, era o que precisava, valeu so fiz uma alteração no codigo...

Comment: #################################### INSERI OPCIONAIS ########################################################################
            $ids = array();
            foreach($veiculo->opcionais->opcional as $opcional)
            { 
            echo $opcional['id'];
            $ids[] = $opcional['id'];
            }
        $opc2 = implode(',', $ids);

          
    #################################### FIM OPCIONAIS ########################################################################

Comment: Se alguma das respostas for válida, poderia validá-la clicando no icon verde abaixo as setas de avaliação...vlw ;)

Comment: Valeu, ajudou muito!